# selenium not able to retrieve/read part of the website

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I was trying to do a automated script to download some foreign exchange price historical data. These data are available at

https://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/historical/

However, if I just use Selenium to retrieve part of the website, I can't find this element in the website no matter how long I waited:

```
<iframe src="https://freeserv.dukascopy.com/2.0/?path=historical_data_feed/index&amp;header=false&amp;availableInstruments=l%3A&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=600&amp;adv=popup" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>
```

Apparently, the only thing selenium can read is the two  elements ahead of the :

```
<script type="text/javascript">DukascopyApplet = {"type":"historical_data_feed","params":{"header":false,"availableInstruments":"l:","width":"100%","height":"600","adv":"popup"}};</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://freeserv.dukascopy.com/2.0/core.js"></script>
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wait for the presence](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) of the frame and then *switch to it*. Then, you can look for the elements inside:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/historical/")

# wait for the frame to load and switch
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
iframe = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".mainContentBody iframe")))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

# print out the bold radio button style texts
for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul > li[data-group][data-instrument] strong"):
    print(item.text)

driver.close()
```

Prints:

```
ADS.DE
ALV.DE
AUD/CAD
AUD/CHF
AUD/JPY
...
VOW3.DE
XAG/USD
XAU/USD
ZAR/JPY
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Two very stupid follow up questions:

1. Why do we need to do `driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)`, I tried the ImplicitWait before but didn't include the switch_to.frame(), it didn't workout
2. I copied everything you wrote down here, but the console is not printing out anything. I tried the following CSS selectors besides yours, all result in not finding anything:
* `li.N-eb-fb-gb`
* `ul > li strong`
I was indeed able to find two `<ul>`s as the webpage shown.

Thanks again!

Comment: OK, I think I got this figured out, if I explicitly put some time to sleep after `driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)`, like `time.sleep(3)`, I can get all your print outputs. But this is really strange. Shouldn't switch waits until all the elements are loaded before switch to it?

Comment: @ShaunZiqinRong time.sleep() is not the best way to tackle timing issues. Use the same `wait.until()` approach here as well. After switching to the frame do `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul > li[data-group][data-instrument] strong")))` and then get the results.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, will selenium wait until it catches all elements of the corresponding selector, or will it just wait until it catches the first one satisfying the selector?

I tested comparing against time.sleep(), seems it is catching all of the satisfying elements.

Comment: @ShaunZiqinRong it catches the first one, but this is a good indicator the page is loaded in this case. Thanks.